# show that $\int_{x} |fgh|d \mu ≤ \|f \|_p \|g\|_q \|h\|_r$

Tags: real-analysis

let p, q, r be real numbers such that $\frac{1}{p}+ \frac{1}{q}+ \frac{1}{r} =1$

and let $f \in L_p \ ( \mu ) \, g \in L {_q} ( \mu) $, and $h \in L_p ( \mu)$

How show that?

$\int_{x} |fgh|d \mu ≤ \|f \|_p \|g\|_q \|h\|_r$

Comment: You could mimic the proof of the Holder inequality maybe

Comment: How is it shown by applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality? or Minkowski's inequality? is this possible to do?

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420381/generalization-of-h%C3%B6lder-inequality