Holder's inequality for $L^p$?
Holder's inequality states that
$$\| fg\|_1 \leq \|f\|_p \|g\|_q$$
when $q = \frac{p}{p-1}$.
Is there a way to bound of the form $\|fg\|_p \leq \|f\|_A \|g\|_B$ for some choice of norms $\|\cdot\|_A$ and $\|\cdot\|_B$?

yes, $\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{A}+\frac{1}{B}$. Just google for generalized Holder inequalities; there’s also a variant for more than two functions.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/420381

Thanks! For some integer $p$, is there always some integers $A$ and $B$ such that $\frac{1}{p} = \frac{1}{A} + \frac{1}{B}$? Or do $A$ and $B$ sometimes have to be non-integer real numbers?

@900edges When $p=1$, only $A=B=2$ works where both are integers.  For the same reason, $A=B=2p$ works for general $p$, but there may be others (e.g. $p=2$ also allows $A=3$ and $B=6$).

Observe that $$|fg|_p=||f|^p|g|^p|_1$$

@RyszardSzwarc I don't know which form you wanted, but you're missing either a $p$th power (on the left side) or a $p$th root (on the right).

@BrianMoehring A misprint. A wanted a $p$ power on the left hand side.
